# Mean monthly NDVI from Sentinel to CSV-files

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, ndvi, sentinel

I am trying to create monthly NDVI maps from Sentinel in Google Earth Engine. The script that I'm using is from things I gathered around the internet. When I try to download this to a CSV-file, I get the error: Error: Image.sample: Unable to find a crs. I know there are multiple questions regarding the monthly mean of datasets. But none try and export them to a csv-file with the coordinates and the corresponding value.

What I have so far:

```
    // Filter geometry and dates
    var S2_SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
        .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2019-12-31') 
        .filterBounds(roi) // filter to ROI
        .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)}) //iterate and 
                                    clips roi over whole collection
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',"less_than", 25); 
        
    // Add NDVI band
    var addNDVI = function(image) {
      var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 
                                  'B4']).rename('NDVI');
      return image.addBands(ndvi);
    };

    // Apply across whole collection 
    var S2_NDVI = S2_SR.map(addNDVI);

    // Select out only NDVI band
    var NDVI_only = ee.ImageCollection(S2_NDVI.select(["NDVI"], 
                                                   ["NDVI"]));
   print(NDVI_only);

    //
    var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
    var years = ee.List.sequence(2017, 2019);

    //calculate average values for red and nir band
    var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function(y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
          return NDVI_only
           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
           .mean()
           .set('month', m).set('year', y);
       });
      }).flatten());

    print('done');

   //creating variables out of collection
    var listOfImages = collection.toList(collection.size());

    var s2017_1 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
    var s2017_2 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1));

    var sentinel2017_01 = s2017_1.sample({
      region: roi,
      geometries: true,
    });
    var sentinel2017_02 = s2017_2.sample({
      region: roi,
      geometries: true,
    });
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: sentinel2017_01, 
      description: 'sentinel2017_01', 
      folder: 'outputSentinel',
      fileFormat: 'CSV'
    });
    Export.table.toDrive({
     collection: sentinel2017_02, 
     description: 'sentinel2017_02', 
     folder: 'outputSentinel',
     fileFormat: 'CSV'
    });
```

here's the link; https://code.earthengine.google.com/b3db6273efd5a08c3089ca69dde5cae3

Anyone with any ideas?